# How to resolve exception(s) thrown when log4j2 rolling file appender triggers?

Tags: log4j2, tomcat8

Logs appear to roll over and archive normally, but on or near the specified trigger time I notice an exception in tomcat catalina.out (sometimes once, other times it floods logs at 1/sec). Any help appreciated.

### Execution Environment:

- Tomcat Version : Apache Tomcat/8.5.3
- JVM Version : 1.8.0_92-b14
- JVM Vendor : Oracle Corporation
- OS Name : Linux
- OS Version : 2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64
- OS Architecture : amd64

### Assembled WAR appears to have the appropriate jars in WEB-INF/lib, including :

- log4j-api-2.6.2.jar
- log4j-core-2.6.2.jar
- log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar
- log4j-web-2.6.2.jar

### Exception:

```
2016-10-27 16:11:24,002 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-2 ERROR Error running command java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/core/impl/Log4jLogEvent$Builder
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.PatternProcessor.formatFileName(PatternProcessor.java:234)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy.purgeAscending(DefaultRolloverStrategy.java:323)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy.purge(DefaultRolloverStrategy.java:306)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy.rollover(DefaultRolloverStrategy.java:524)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.rollover(RollingFileManager.java:220)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.rollover(RollingFileManager.java:155)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CronTriggeringPolicy.rollover(CronTriggeringPolicy.java:127)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CronTriggeringPolicy.access$100(CronTriggeringPolicy.java:40)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CronTriggeringPolicy$CronTrigger.run(CronTriggeringPolicy.java:144)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationScheduler$CronRunnable.run(ConfigurationScheduler.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

### Exception2:

```
The web application [my-services] appears to have started a thread named [Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

### log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info" name="MyLog" packages="">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="baseDir">/var/log/tomcat</Property>
    <Property name="appName">MyLog</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${baseDir}/${appName}.log" immediateFlush="true"
      filePattern="${baseDir}/$${date:yyyy}/$${date:MM}/${appName}-$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{%d %p{INFO=INFO_,WARN=WARN_} %c{3.} (%M:%L) [%t] %m%n%ex}{FATAL=Magenta,TRACE=Normal White}" />
      <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0 * * ?"/>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="2">
          <IfFileName glob="*/${appName}-*log.gz" />
          <IfLastModified age="90d" />
        </Delete>
      </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{%d %p{INFO=INFO_,WARN=WARN_} %c{3.} (%M:%L) [%t] %m%n%ex}{FATAL=Magenta,TRACE=Normal White}" />
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
      <!--<AppenderRef ref="Console"/>-->
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1">
    <display-name>My Services</display-name>

    <!-- log4j2 configuration file -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
        <param-value>log4j2.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- my servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>my-services</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>my.package, com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>my-services</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

### pom.xml dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- version properties -->
    <jersey.version>2.23.1</jersey.version>
    <jackson.version>2.7.2</jackson.version>
    <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jersey and Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey w/Tomcat 8 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Noticed a potentially related exception from Tomcat Catalina Engine and included it in the question detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1259) with lo4j2 2.6.2 leaking threads in Tomcat webapps when they shutdown. I suspect you see ClassNotFoundExceptions because an orphaned thread is trying to load classes. This is especially likely since you're using the [CronTriggeringPolicy](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1259?focusedCommentId=15454818&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15454818) to force log rolling at midnight, but restarting your webapp before that policy can execute.

A fix has been issued in lo4j2 2.7. Try bumping your version.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have an older version of log4j 2 in the Tomcat server lib folder.

What do you see if you do this in your web app? That should tell you which jar Log4jLogEvent was loaded from.

```
System.out.println(
    Log4jLogEvent.class.getResource( 
        "/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/impl/Log4jLogEvent.class"));
```

Comment: jar:file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.5.3/webapps/liveservices/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-core-2.6.2.jar!/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/impl/Log4jLogEvent.class

Comment: If you look inside that jar with WinZip or something, does it contain the Log4jLogEvent$Builder class?

Comment: Yes, it is there.

Comment: Puzzled how you can get a NoClassDefFoundError... Do you know when this error occurred? Was the app reloaded?

Comment: Seems to occur when the log rolls over, which right now is controlled by the cron trigger policy (daily at midnight). Always see this error at least once, and occasionally it will spew 1/sec. If I get the spewing case, I have to restart tomcat to stop it.

Comment: Agree that the no class def found is confusing.  One thing I just realized is that I am using an inplace war so my build environment and tomcat's deploy environment are sharing the same files.  I will retry with a typical deployed war and see if this makes a difference. (Maybe something is pulling the rug out from under tomcat).